# Firefox can find location but Safari cannot

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, geolocation

I am trying to get my code working with Safari on a Mac (**does work on an iOS device** and even in the iPhone Simulator…). In Firefox it works fine but in Safari it doesn't:

```
  if ($('.latitude-field').length && navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
      var lon = pos.coords.longitude;

      $('.latitude-field').val(lat);
      $('.longitude-field').val(lon);

      $('.geolocation-status').text('Location: ' + lat + ', ' + lon);
    }, function(err) {
      $('.geolocation-status').text('Unable to find location.' + err.message);
    });
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does it mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: It returns an error saying that the current location cannot be found. I am in an area with more than 10 Wi-Fi networks, and both Mobile Safari and Firefox can find my location.

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but does Safari on Mac support that feature? And what's the output you get (in `err.message`)? Or is an exception thrown?

Comment: I didn't realise geolocation worked on desktop browsers...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the System Preferences panel and the Safari? Both have a Security item where there is an option to allow or not the location to be obtained.

Comment: I haven't checked the system preferences yet. I'll take a look at it as soon as my computer is turned on again. Man… sleeping is boring and a giant waste of time, especially for a programmer.